# Compare CSV file with extra Column data

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two CSV files with once CSV having an extra column with ticket number. I am trying to create another csv file by comparing the two with output like below with ticket number matching the Alert_ID.

```
csv1
Alert_ID    Server  Type    Timestamp   Severity 
1234        Srv1    WIN 2023-03-10  Critical
1235        Srv1    Net 2023-03-9   Critical
1236        Srv2    WIN 2023-03-8   Critical
1237        Srv3    WIN 2023-03-10  Critical


csv2
Alert_ID    Server  Type    Timestamp   Severity  Ticket    
1234        Srv1    WIN 2023-03-10  Critical   INC1
1236        Srv2    WIN 2023-03-8   Critical   INC3
1238        Srv4    NET 2023-02-10  Critical   INC01
1239        Srv5    NET 2023-02-20  Critical   INC02     
 

Expected Output

csv3
Alert_ID    Server  Type    Timestamp   Severity  Ticket    
1234        Srv1    WIN 2023-03-10  Critical   INC1
1235        Srv1    Net 2023-03-9   Critical   
1236        Srv2    WIN 2023-03-8   Critical   INC3
1237        Srv3    WIN 2023-03-10  Critical
```

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv .\csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv .\csv2.csv
#csv2 | where-object { $csv1.Alert_ID -match $_.Alert_ID} | export-csv .\csv3.csv -notype
```

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\csv1.csv |Update-Object (Import-Csv .\csv2.csv) -on Alert_ID |Export-Csv .\Csv3.Csv -NoType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to use an external ([Join-Object](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994)) module for this. You might also use the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) for this (which is probably slower):

```
$csv1 = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Alert_ID, Server, Type, Timestamp,  Severity
    1234, Srv1,   WIN,  2023-03-10, Critical
    1235, Srv1,   Net,  2023-03-9,  Critical
    1236, Srv2,   WIN,  2023-03-8,  Critical
    1237, Srv3,   WIN,  2023-03-10, Critical
'@

$csv2 = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Alert_ID, Server, Type, Timestamp,  Severity, Ticket
    1234, Srv1,   WIN,  2023-03-10, Critical, INC1
    1236, Srv2,   WIN,  2023-03-8,  Critical, INC3
'@

$csv1 + $csv2 |Group-Object -Property Alert_ID |Foreach-Object { @($_.Group)[-1] } |Format-Table

Alert_ID Server Type Timestamp  Severity Ticket
-------- ------ ---- ---------  -------- ------
1234     Srv1   WIN  2023-03-10 Critical INC1
1235     Srv1   Net  2023-03-9  Critical
1236     Srv2   WIN  2023-03-8  Critical INC3
1237     Srv3   WIN  2023-03-10 Critical
```

**Explanation:**

- `$csv2 + $csv1` adds the to objects list as one list
- `Group-Object -Property Alert_ID` Groups the objects by the `Alert-ID` property
- `Foreach-Object { @($_.Group)[-1] }` takes the last object in the group property list (presuming that `Group-Object` respects the order of the original object list, which is actually not defined in the help, see also: [Question: Group-Object group order `#19307`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19307))

Using the ([JoinModule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule/)), this would be similar to: `$Csv1 |Merge-Object $Csv2 -on Alert_ID`

---

Based on the revised question:

```
$csv2 = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Alert_ID, Server, Type, Timestamp,  Severity, Ticket
    1234, Srv1,   WIN,  2023-03-10, Critical, INC1
    1236, Srv2,   WIN,  2023-03-8,  Critical, INC3
    1238, Srv4,   NET,  2023-02-10, Critical, INC01
    1239, Srv5,   NET,  2023-02-20, Critical, INC02
'@

$csv1 + $csv2 |Where-Object { $csv1.Alert_ID -eq $_.Alert_ID } |
Group-Object -Property Alert_ID |Foreach-Object { @($_.Group)[-1] } |Format-Table

Alert_ID Server Type Timestamp  Severity Ticket
-------- ------ ---- ---------  -------- ------
1234     Srv1   WIN  2023-03-10 Critical INC1
1235     Srv1   Net  2023-03-9  Critical
1236     Srv2   WIN  2023-03-8  Critical INC3
1237     Srv3   WIN  2023-03-10 Critical
```

**Explanation:**

- `Where-Object { $csv1.Alert_ID -eq $_.Alert_ID }` filters only the objects that are only listed in `Csv1` based on the [common comparison operators feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features): *when the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression.*

Using the ([JoinModule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule/)), this would be similar to: `$Csv1 |Update-Object $Csv2 -on Alert_ID`

Comment: Hi Ron.. i have made some changes to CSV2 which has more ticket reference but i need the output csv3 which has alert id on csv1